# How do I sum a string of space delimited 1's and 0's in an R data frame in

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a column that has a bunch of strings like '0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0'

They are all the same length but contain different amounts of 1's and 0's. How can I sum them up in r?

Answer (score 6):

If they're strings, you can use `scan` to create a numeric vector and just `sum` that:

```
sum(scan(text = "0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0", quiet = TRUE))
# [1] 3
```

---

If it were a column, you can still use `scan`. The approach might be something like:

```
rowSums(matrix(scan(text = as.character(df$V1)), ncol = 8, byrow = TRUE))
```

Replace "`df$V1`" with whatever column your data actually is in, and "`ncol = 8`" by however many columns you really should have.

---

`vapply` + `strsplit` would also be a good option. This is similar to [@karen's approach with `sapply`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48911758/1270695), but instead of looping through everything twice, you just do it once:

```
vapply(strsplit(as.character(x), " ", TRUE), function(y)
       sum(as.integer(y)), integer(1L))
```

---

But an even faster option would be to read the data in using `fread` from "data.table" or `dstrstplit` from "iotools" and then use `rowSums()`

```
library(data.table)
rowSums(fread(paste(x, collapse = "\n")))

library(iotools)
rowSums(dstrsplit(x, sep = " ", col_types = rep("integer", 10)))
```

---

Here are some benchmarks. First, sample data and functions to test:

```
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(V1 = replicate(10000, paste(sample(c(0, 1), 10, TRUE), collapse = " ")))

library(data.table) # For fun_fread()
library(iotools)    # For fun_iotools()

fun_scan <- function(x) {
  nc <- length(scan(text = as.character(x[1]), quiet = TRUE))
  rowSums(matrix(scan(text = as.character(x), quiet = TRUE), ncol = nc, byrow = TRUE))
}

fun_vapply <- function(x) {
  vapply(strsplit(as.character(x), " ", TRUE), function(y) sum(as.integer(y)), integer(1L))
}

fun_sapply <- function(x) {
  sapply(as.character(x), function(col) { sum(sapply(strsplit(col, ' '), as.integer))})
}

fun_fread <- function(x) rowSums(fread(paste(x, collapse = "\n")))

fun_iotools <- function(x) {
  nc <- length(scan(text = as.character(x[1]), quiet = TRUE))
  rowSums(dstrsplit(as.character(x), sep = " ", col_types = rep("integer", nc)))
}
```

Check that everything is equal:

```
all.equal(fun_scan(mydf$V1), fun_vapply(mydf$V1))
# [1] TRUE

all.equal(unname(fun_sapply(mydf$V1)), fun_vapply(mydf$V1))
# [1] TRUE

all.equal(fun_fread(mydf$V1), fun_vapply(mydf$V1))
# [1] TRUE

all.equal(fun_fread(mydf$V1), fun_iotools(mydf$V1))
# [1] TRUE
```

Now, the benchmarks:

```
library(microbenchmark)
res <- microbenchmark(fun_scan(mydf$V1), fun_vapply(mydf$V1), 
                      fun_sapply(mydf$V1), fun_fread(mydf$V1), fun_iotools(mydf$V1))
# Unit: milliseconds
#                  expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#     fun_scan(mydf$V1)  52.071714  54.473772  57.257971  55.869307  58.200922  74.248057   100
#   fun_vapply(mydf$V1)  20.477943  22.079925  24.796633  23.613694  26.205056  46.857130   100
#   fun_sapply(mydf$V1) 267.655633 281.656375 308.750804 296.128511 319.318740 449.806432   100
#    fun_fread(mydf$V1)   8.112898   8.391891   9.154349   8.643196   9.434840  16.967090   100
#  fun_iotools(mydf$V1)   4.436515   4.608810   4.967436   4.751517   5.114486   8.690872   100

autoplot(res)
```

[image]

Comment: `scan(text` can solve many many problems :)

Comment: @zx8754, plus on something like this, it will be fast.

Answer (score 3):

I would do:

```
strTest <- '0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0'
sum(sapply(strsplit(strTest, ' '), as.integer))
```

Considering that it is a column named test_col, then:

```
sapply(test_col, function(col) { sum(sapply(strsplit(col, ' '), as.integer))})
```

Comment: This will work, but it's not a good idea the way it's implemented.